# What is the difference between various flight search sites' price forecasts?

Tags: air-travel, planning, tickets, airlines

I did a search on Kayak for an upcoming flight and it's price trend suggests waiting, citing 60% confidence that the price of the ticket will do down. However when I search for the exact same flight on Bing Travel it suggests buying the ticket, citing 80% confidence that the price of the ticket will go up. The real stumper is that Bing's results are powered by Kayak.

Does each site use a different algorithim to determine the price trend? Does anyone have any advice on which is more accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they use different algorithms.

Bing made the [switch to use Kayak back in 2011](http://www.tnooz.com/2011/03/15/news/bing-makes-the-switch-to-kayak-for-flights/), and their partnership meant that:

> Bing Travel flights has retained its “look and feel,” but with the
>   **exception of Bing’s Price Predictor**, the tools and filters basically
>   are the same.

Recently, Kayak produced its own new price forecaster, and if you'd like to read more about how that works, they have an article on their site: [KAYAK Launches Price Forecasts For Flights](https://www.kayak.com/news/kayak-launches-price-forecasts-for-flights.bd.html).

But yes, long story short - different forecasting algorithms, and pretty much the same flights.

Comment: Any idea which is more accurate?

Comment: @gorideyourbike - it's like predicting the weather, they could both be wrong or right and it's hard to know :)  I don't know of anyone that's actually tested their reliability, no, sorry.

Comment: However, [Kayak claims theirs is better](http://www.tnooz.com/2013/01/15/news/kayak-adds-price-forecasts-to-us-and-uk-fare-search-saying-its-better-than-bing-travel/) ;)

Comment: Plus kayak gives a % to indicate how certain they are.  Microsoft's original Farecast predictions were [independently verified to be 75% accurate](http://www.tnooz.com/2013/01/15/news/kayak-adds-price-forecasts-to-us-and-uk-fare-search-saying-its-better-than-bing-travel/)